# Can this code be improved/refactored/optimised/compacted anymore? I've exhausted my creative juices and looking for your wisdom

Tags: c, cs50

This is my code for the CS50 Mario (more comfortable).
Answers can be found all over the net however I wrote this myself.

I would like to refactor to its maximum potential (just for my own improvement I'm not enrolled or anything).

I have chosen to create 2 functions and called them in the `main` function.

Can this be be improved or refactored anymore or is this as good as it gets?

A quick outline of the code:

Firstly it asks for a valid input of an amount of rows to be built (an integer between 0 and 550) and then builds a Mario wall like this:
#  #

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void build_wall(int num_rows);
void get_rows(int n);
int rows = 0;
int spaces = 0;
int bricks = 0;
int main(void)

{
    get_rows(rows);
    build_wall(rows);
}
void get_rows(int n)
{
    do
    {
    printf("How many rows would you like? ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("\n");
    printf("You would like %d rows.\n", rows);
    }
    while (rows <= 0 || rows >=550);
}

void build_wall(int num_rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) ///number of rows
    {
        for(spaces = 0; spaces < num_rows-i-1; spaces++ )       // first spaces
            {
                printf(" ");
            }

        for(bricks = 0; bricks < i+1; bricks++)             //   first wall bricks
            {
                printf("#");
            }

        {
            printf("  ");                                   //Middle spaces
        }

        for(bricks = 0; bricks < i+1; bricks++)            // Second wall bricks
            {
                printf("#");
            }
    printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. Avoid global variables.

Comment: Post this question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Variables `spaces` and `bricks` can be scoped to `build_wall` function

Comment: `putchar( )` instead of `printf( )`, passing `rows` to `get_rows()` then ignoring that variable (using a global one instead... Turn up warnings and ask the compiler to review this code...

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should not assume that anyone knows what you are talking about when you say "CS50 Mario (more comfortable)". You are taking a specific course. We don't. Therefore you musn't assume we know your context. You have to describe it. Otherwise how would we know if your code is overly complicates, or even correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked, so here is an answer. Factor out the several loops and a couple of `printf()`s would be a start. And make better use of 'i' (renamed to 'r' as in 'row_counter'.)

```
void out( char c, int n ) {
    while( n-- )
        putchar( c );
}

void build_wall( int nrows ) {
    for ( int r = 1; r <= nrows; r++ ) {
        out( ' ', nrows - r ); // left indent
        out( '#', r ); // left wall
        out( ' ', 2 ); // 'chimney'
        out( '#', r ); // right wall
        out( '\n', 1 ); // done with this row
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Since OP reports problems (misunderstanding?) integrating the above function into the original code, why bother with functions at all. This is a single purpose program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int rows = 0, c, n;
    do {
        printf( "How many rows would you like? (2-30)" );
        scanf( "%d", &rows );
        printf( "\nYou would like %d rows.\n", rows );
    } while( rows < 2 || 30 < rows ); // be reasonable

    for ( int r = 1; r <= rows; r++ )
        for( int step = 0; step < 5; step++ ) {
            switch( step ) {
                case 0: c = ' '; n = rows - r; break;
                case 1: c = '#'; n = r; break;
                case 2: c = ' '; n = 2; break; // 'chimney'
                case 3: c = '#'; n = r; break;
                case 4: c = '\n'; n = 1; break;
            }
            while( n-- )
                putchar( c );
        }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT2:** In fact, while we are at it, replace the inner `for()`, the `switch()`, and the `while()`. `printf()` offers the facilities needed. For convenience, an infinite loop makes it easy to play multiple times.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for( ;; ) {
        int rows = 0;
        do {
            printf( "How many rows would you like? (2-30)" );
            scanf( "%d", &rows );
            printf( "\nYou would like %d rows.\n", rows );
        } while( rows < 2 || 30 < rows ); // be reasonable, eh?

        char *x = "                              "
                  "##############################";

        for ( int r = 1; r <= rows; r++ )
            printf( "%.*s  %.*s\n", rows, x+30-rows+r, r, x+30 );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fe203 thanks so much for your time to help. However I cant seem to make the code compile. I added the `#include <stdio.h>` however still nothing. Any pointers :)

Comment: @DavidWyatt These two functions should **replace** your one function `build_wall`... You keep your `main()` and `get_rows()` where they are. Are you still using those parts of your code? What do you mean "still nothing"? Compiler errors or warnings???

Comment: Many thanks again for your help. I took a year and a half to contemplate your code (It made nooo sense to me back when you wrote it). I have another  question if you don't mind (Pls bear in mind i'm still a super noob). Would this code occur in the real world? Specifically the way it iterates over the string to make the different levels rather than using a for loop. Why is this method prefered or more optimal compared to a for loop? Or are you just showing off with some esoteric wizardry? Genine question. Hope all is well :)

Comment: Is it considered pointer arithmetic in a string?

Comment: @DavidWyatt Long forgotten... but thanks for the rep. points :-)... `x+30-rows+r` and `x+30` are "pointer arithmetic" expressions, adding an integer value to `x`. "Would this code occur in the Real World?" Yes it does. When "formatting output", some authors write cumbersome, verbose (hard to read) versions using myriad variables. My preference is for "crisp, clean, minimal" code that utilises the capabilities of tested library functions like `printf()`. Don't be afraid to learn! Cheers! :-)